# How to let my configured session work in AJAX

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, session

I have this interceptor function where I configure my session.

```
if (request.getRequestURL().indexOf("profile") > 0) {
    if (session.getAttribute("access").equals("sub-admin")) {
        System.out.println("This is request to profile - admin");
    } else {
        System.out.println("This is request to profile - user");
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/error"); //ERROR HERE YOU ARE JUST A USER NOT AN ADMIN, I WILL REDIRECT YOU TO ERROR PAGE
    }
}
```

Now I am using jQuery and AJAX in my front end.

If I am just a user and I will access `localhost:8080/sample/profile`, It will work. It redirected me to the error page.

But, when I access it in my menu in the home page and click profile, it doesn't work.

I think it is because I am using AJAX and the path doesn't change, the view only.

```
$.ajax({
    url: ROOT_URL + '/sample/profile',
    type: "get",
    dataType: "text"
}).done(function(data) {
    $('#idcontainer').html(data);
});
```

How do you let the session work in my AJAX front end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to handle the redirect from an AJAX call, you can take a look at the following question:

- [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

A better solution might be to check if the request is AJAX, and send a JSON response with an HTTP status that you can handle on the frontend:

JSON Response:

```
{
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "You must be logged in to view this content",
    "code": 401
}
```

And in your interceptor:

```
boolean ajax = "XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With"));
if (ajax) {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    response.getWriter().write(responseToClient);
    response.getWriter().flush();
    response.getWriter().close();
} else {
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/error");
}
```

Note that not all AJAX libraries include the `X-Requested-With` header, but jQuery along with most other modern libraries do.

Then in your JavaScript function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ROOT_URL + '/sample/profile',
    type: "get",
    dataType: "text"
}).done(function(data) {
    // handle success HTML
}).fail(function (data) {
    // parse JSON and alert error message
});
```

In addition, it seems that you're using the AJAX request to replace the contents of the page with the HTML returned from the AJAX request. Instead of using a JSON response, you could also just return the error HTML instead and display that in the same way that you are returning the profile HTML content:

HTML response:

```
<h1>Error</h1>

<p class="error">You must be logged in to view this content.</p>
```

And set the HTML the same way as in your `done` callback:

```
.fail(function (data) {
    $('#idcontainer').html(data);
});
```

Comment: That is just a mistake, I just edited it. Have you other examples on handling the redirect?